# Сайты для решения задач по программированию?

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый день изучил основы js и хочу закрепить свои знания путём решения задач по программированию и тех которые обычно дают при собеседовании. Что то типо: из вложенного массива сделать плоский массив и т.д. С английским не очень желательно сайты с русским языком.

Comment: такие задачи дают на очень тупых собеседованиях :) тупые собеседователи, из той же серии "засуньте жирафа в холодильник", от вас требовать будут понимание работы кода, умение делать проекты, поэтому вместо задач для собеседования выберите себе лучше проект, который вы хотите сделать (желательно полезный хотя бы для вас) и вот на нем вы получите гораздо более полезные навыки, которые и пригодятся и на собеседовании и в работе. P.S. а хотите задач - поищите просто олимпиадные задачи по программированию :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ ))

Comment: На русском можно перерешать все задания к разделам на https://learn.javascript.ru/, если ещё не.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
www.codewars.com
www.freecodecamp.org
leetcode.com

а так же :

e-olymp.com/ru
codeforces.com
acm.timus.ru
codecombat.com
```